# jQuery Countdown shows no Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement jQuery countdown using [this](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) reference

**Code:**

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Merry Christmas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- countdown -->
    <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
    <!-- countdown --> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It shows nothing but **blank page**. No **console errors**.

The fiddle can be seen below

https://jsfiddle.net/n4nmgkgc/1/

Comment: It looks like you haven't included jQuery

Comment: Yes he has, in the head

Comment: Insert all your code(last script) within `document.ready`.

Comment: Included a fiddle. JS and CSS as external resources. Please check update

Comment: You are linking the files via http, but JSFiddle is in https, so that already causes problems to start with (at least in Firefox). Check the log for details (FF: press Ctrl+Shift+K, then reload the page).

Comment: Its working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/n4nmgkgc/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script at the bottom of your page needs to be like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var newYear = new Date();
    newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
});
</script>
```

Like @Tarafder Ashek E Elahi said, jquery.countdown is a dependency of jquery.plugin

Answer (score 1):

**jquery.countdown.js** has a dependency on **jquery.plugin.js**. Try changing the loading sequence of these two JS files like below. Load the "jquery.plugin.js" first, then load the "jquery.countdown.js".

```
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your script , just that the external libraries/resources your loading is over `http` protocol, `jsfiddle` is not working properly as its blocked.

but that should not stop you when running the same script on your browser.

**Workaround:**

Anyway as a workaround I have dumped all those resources manually on your `jsfiddle` and your `count down` script is working fine.

[Working CountDown Timer @JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/n4nmgkgc/8/)

Also you need to understand the dependency of the libraries your loading for your script , because in your case your `jquery.plugin.js` is dependent on `jquery.js` and `jquery.countdown.js` is  dependent on `jquery.plugin.js`.

so below is the order  in which you need to load the external libraries (Top to Bottom):

- jquery.js
- jquery.plugin.js
- jquery.countdown.js

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add style 
please add it

in head

```
 <style type="text/css">
            #defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
        </style>
```

and refresh page.. clock will show in page.. try fast